# How to apply color to all element between the first and the last without giving a number to nth-child()?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to know how to apply the color or background color to all elements between the first and the last element without adding number into `nth-child()`.

Assume that I have a dynamic stack of `p` on a page. And I'd like them to be highlighted except both ends (for some reasons). Or make them a different color.

**HTML**

```
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
<p>child</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
p:first-child, p:last-child {
    background-color:yellow;
}
p:nth-child() {
    background-color:#eeeeeee;
}
```

To make it clearer. I also make a live version here : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/s95a1rue/2/

Is it possible to just use html and css (not jquery nor javascript)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `:not` like:

```
p {
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
p:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s95a1rue/7/)**

Comment: @HashemQolami - ah I didn't see that you had made a fiddle under dystroy's answer. Well done. And yes, you should have ;)

Answer (score 6):

Just like this :

```
p {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
p:first-child, p:last-child {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

The second selector has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the first one, that's why it works.

Note : be careful that `#eeeeeee` (7 e) isn't a valid color.

Answer (score 0):

The `:first-child` & `:last-child` tags take precedence. Applying a background to all rows and then specifying something different for first/last should work.

```
p{
 background-color:#aaaaaa;
 }

p:first-child, p:last-child{
 background-color:#ffffff;
 }
```